# Old Knight Greatshield hidden passive?

Tags: dark-souls-2

I was fooling around on dark souls 2 last night and I read the description of the [Old Knight Greatshield](http://darksouls.wikia.com/wiki/Old_Knight_Greatshield) which states:

***An undated ancient greatshield***

***Wielded by a warrior from a time so ancient that there exists no record of his endeavors. Has extremely low durability.***

***Sometimes, just as a thing falls to pieces, it unleashes its last flash of great power...***

I noticed the part where it says  "*Sometimes, just as a thing falls to pieces, it unleashes its last flash of great power...*" and that made me wonder if there was some sort of passive when you break the shield. I went out and took it down to zero durability about 5 times with no result. So is there actually a hidden passive for it, or is From just yanking my chain?

Answer (score 7):

The Old Knight series of equipment all have this description, but it has been (as of 2014/08/13) determined that there is actually no hidden effect. From what I can interpret, the description is actually a reference to the surprising quality of these weapons. They look broken-down with the blue-green color indicating possible corrosion and yet they tend to have some of the better stats in the game, the only downside being their relatively low durability (probably an indication of how broken down they are).

So the description of "just as a thing falls to pieces, it unleashes its flash of great power" is actually a reference to its *current state* being the "flash of great power".

Comment: With the Bracing Knuckle ring (and I believe there's another item to ward off item degradation... it's escaping me for now) this gear is surprisingly strong. Takes most people by surprise in PvP.

Comment: @Ben Oh yeah, I run a +10 Raw Old Knight Hammer (Raw because the hammer has no scaling so I don't lose anything) and that thing hits like a *truck*.

Answer (score -3):

If you are wearing the complete set and they are all broken, it nearly makes you invincible. But you have to wear the complete set and all have to be broken.

Stats are like:

95% resistance on every stat(including physical and magical). Except for fire and poison which are 100%

Item (every stat except fire and poison)
/(fire and poison resistance)

- Helm (15%)/(15%)
- Gauntlets (10%)/(10%)
- Boots (10%)/(10%)
- Armour (25%)/(30%)
- Shield (20%)/(20%)
- Sword (15%)/(15%)

Comment: I don't know who would upvote this answer. I'm pretty sure this is a lie. An armor set making you invincible? Got any sources for that? ;)